# host name lookup failure when sending using sendmail

Tags: sendmail

I am trying to setup sendmail to send mail via a Mail Relay
I know the Mail Relay works as its been tested elsewhere

I followed quite a few guidance pages and the following is in the sendmail.mc file:

```
define(`SMART_HOST', `10.*.*.*')dnl
define(`RELAY_MAILER',`esmtp')dnl
define(`RELAY_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 587')dnl
define(`ESMTP_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 587')dnl
define(`confAUTH_MECHANISMS', `EXTERNAL GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
FEATURE(`authinfo',`hash -o /etc/mail/authinfo/authinfo.db')dnl
define(`confAUTH_OPTIONS', `A p')dnl
TRUST_AUTH_MECH(`EXTERNAL DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
FEATURE(`nocanonify', `canonify_hosts')
```

But when any mail is triggered through it, I always get the same error:

```
Nov 22 08:51:04 localhost sm-mta[17199]: 3AH97jas061031: to=<steven.rothera@test.com>, ctladdr=<www-data@operations> (33/33), delay=4+23:43:19, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=65370405, relay=10.*.*.*, dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Name server: 10.*.*.*: host name lookup failure
```

Can anyone help me as to what might be the issue here?
I'm struggling to find the answer based on anyone elses posts.
Most other posts seem to relate to people using an incorrect SMART HOST URL but I'm using an IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## sendmail: smart host as IP address

If you want to use ip address as smart host then put it in square brackets.
Also use specific IP address (no wildcards: `10.*.*.*` => e.g. `10.0.0.1`).

```
define(`SMART_HOST', `[10.0.0.1]')dnl
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked, For some reason I didn't spot that documented anywhere

Comment: It is documented "somewhere" but it is a non obvious place for beginners.